# Collectionviewsource - different Thread owns it

Tags: wpf, multithreading, dispatch

I've got a new Problem here. I've got a MainWindow in which is a ContentGrid and in this is a Frame. Now I've created different Pages which can be shown in this "content-area". In One of these pages there is a Datagrid bound to a CollectionViewSource which Source is a Database (via EntityFramework). Now, when a Change on this Database-Table happens (solved via ServiceBroker and SQLDependency, firing works fine) The Datagrid have to update.
**Now the Problem:**
The "Dependency_OnChange"-Event is working in the MainWindow-Thread. When i try to access the CollectionViewSource of the Page to Update it (cvs.View.Refresh) i get an Exception that this is not possible because of another Thread which own this CVS.

I've tried it with different Dispatching like:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(()=>
                {
                    cvs.Source = _db.Table.OrderByDescending(nr => nr.Date).Take(200);
                    cvs.View.Refresh();
                }));
```

This Codeblock doesn't brings an Exception but i wont update the UI too... It seems that it does nothing.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You data grid will update if your LINQ query evaluates. Right now it just specifies the LINQ IEnumerable but is not evaluating it.

```
    cvs.Source = _db.Table.OrderByDescending(nr => nr.Date).Take(200).ToList();
```

should do the evaluation of the LINQ  for you...

Although I must say your `cvs.View.Refresh()` call is very expensive as it causes entire grid to refresh. You may have to consider a better design here.

Why dont you set the `dataGrid.ItemsSource = _db.Table.DefaultView` as the item source to the datagrid directly. I guess if your table updates (and peforms `_db.Table.AcceptChanges();`) the view would automatically notify the changes to the grid and grid would possibly update itself faster!

But thats just my opinion as I am not aware of your threading context here. But still do try and let me know.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your tip but when i set the ItemsSource of the Datagrid directly to database with this :
` datagrid.ItemsSource = _db.Table;`
then the datagrid **doesnt**' update automatically when a new entry in database is written ... :(

Comment: Did you try `Table.AcceptChanges()` when you receive that event of DB update? Also if that is not working either, did you try my original tip about `.ToList()`?

Comment: ok try a last tip ... instead of `application.current.dispatcher.Invoke` try `cvs.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` (with `.ToList()`)

Comment: Ok... Ive done it like this:
´CollectionViewSource cvs = __calls.FindResource("cvsCalls") as CollectionViewSource;
                cvs.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        cvs.Source = _db.Anrufe.OrderByDescending(nr => nr.Datum).Take(200).ToList();
                    }));´

Doesnt Work :( ... Grid is not Updating automatically